# What version will be after an adhoc version directly from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Let's say, I installed an adhoc version on the device via a link on the web site.  Now if I hook up the device and update directly using Xcode.  What would the app version on the device be?  (adhoc or development)

Comment: It would be whatever build configuration you have set for the scheme you use in Xcode, usually Debug.

Answer (score 0):

"Version" isn't the right word here.

Rather, an app build (e.g. an `.ipa`) has several build settings that affect it. In the case of Adhoc/Enterprise/AppStore/Develop differences, important ones are:

- Bundle identifier
- Provisioning profile
- Signing certificate

You can specify different values for each of these within Xcode using [build configurations and schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html).

By default, Xcode creates "debug" and "release" configurations and one scheme for you. You can view your apps configurations by selecting the *project* in the file hierarchy > your project in the left side bar > info:

[image: How to view build configuration]

You can also create your own build configurations by pressing the `+` button below the existing configurations and then choosing a configuration to "duplicate" as a starting point.

Most often, you likely will *want* to do this if you support AdHoc/Enterprise/etc in addition to AppStore builds.

This default scheme is set to use `debug` configuration when you "build" or "run" and `release` for "archiving". You can verify this by clicking on the "schemes" drop down > "edit" scheme.

[image]

Again, you can also create your own scheme too and specify which configurations should be used for "build," "run," and "archiving."

Point being, depending on which "scheme" you have selected and the settings for which "configuration" is set to use, this will determine the bundle identifier, provisioning profile, certificate, et all build settings used.

Lastly, in my own experience, Xcode may or may not be happy replacing an AdHoc app on your device with a Development build. That is, if they use the same bundle identifier.

It *may* give a cryptic error complaining to you should you try. However, YMMV depending on the Xcode version you're using (I see this when I use Xcode 7 but haven't tried with Xcode 8).

In this case, you can simply delete the AdHoc build first and then install the Development build.

Alternatively, you can use different bundle identifiers for AdHoc and Development builds, which will allow you to have both installed on the same device.